# How to read a filepath from a openfiledialog to an array of the containing file

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want to use 2 different buttons. One button to open an openfiledialog for the user to select a certain file, then they can click on the generate button to use the file selected to add all its contents to an array.

How do i get that file path to work in the `System.IO.ReadAllLines(filepath)`

i have this code for the open file dialog :

```
private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;


    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string sFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        string[] arrAllFiles = openFileDialog.FileNames;  
        txtScriptfile.Text = arrAllFiles[0];
    }

        }
```

And here i want to use the file path in the read all lines :

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sThirdID = "";
    string sSiteName = "";
    string sFile = "";
    FilePathScript = "@\"" + txtScriptfile.Text + "\"";
    FilePathSite = "@\"" + txtSiteFile.Text +"\"";
    FilePathDestinationFolder = "@\"" + txtdestinationFolder.Text + "\"";
    txtScriptfile.Text = FilePathScript;
    txtSiteFile.Text = FilePathSite;
    txtdestinationFolder.Text = FilePathDestinationFolder;

    string[] Scriptlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePathScript);
    string[] Sitelines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePathSite);
```

Comment: Why you add @" " to the paths? If you intend to make them verbatim strings out of them, you dont need it. its only neccessary to add the @"" to a string if you set it in your code so that the compiler knows to ignore special chars and you dont have to escape them.

Comment: _"How do i get that file path to work "_ In what way it does **not** work currently?

Comment: If you want to select just one file then you don't need that `MultiSelect=True`. Just use the `FileName` property. Then your attempt to put the selected file between double quotes is wrong (just use "\"") and useless. The ReadAllLines method knows how to handle spaces in filenames.

Comment: 1. in your problem description, you say "user to select a certain file ... to add all its contents to an array" - if the user is to select _a_ file, why are you setting `Multiselect=true`? 2. why do you set `sFileName`, then never use it? 3. Why don't you use `sFileName` to set `txtScriptFile.Text` (after setting `Multiselect=false`) 4. Why do you initialize `sThirdId`, `sSiteName`, and `sFile` and never use them? 5. what is all that business with adding _literal_ `@` at the beginning and \ at either end of your filenames?

Comment: Thank you BosesB. that clarifies it alittle bit. thats why i was trying to add it into the variable. I thought i needed to have it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one file, not multiple, so drop the `Multiselect=true` or set `Multiselect=false`. With a single select, you want `openFileDialog.FileName` stored in your text control ... clean up the rest of `Choose_Click`.

`Generate_Click` is a bit of a mess in some ways, but is actually close to what you want: You do nothing with `sThirdID`, `sSiteName`, and `sFile`, so get rid of them. Your treatment of filenames is a bit confusing: when dealing with string literals, you have to indicate them with double-quotes front and back; you also have to take special steps to deal with or "escape" backslashes, unless you use the special notation of preceding the entire string literal with a `@` character, indicating a [verbatim string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx). However, the filenames in your textboxes should have been set by the user selecting them from a system Open dialog, so there should be no extra treatment of them needed.

So let's take the one filename for which you've provided the most detail and look at it, `txtScriptFile.Text`: if you pass this filename straight into `File.ReadAllLines()`, it should return the array of strings just as you have it written ... *provided* the user selected a valid text file when the program was run (e.g., one of the source code files for this project, for example).

So the next thing would be, what are you to do with the array of strings once you have the file loaded? It's going to be hard to verify that you succeeded at the task without showing your results from the program somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John. The unused string variables I use later in the generate function once i have the file into the array. The generate click function was just the extract from the start before my main functionality is programmed. So u say it will work if i just add the filepath directly from the openfiledialog to a global variable and put in the brackets of the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines? and that i dont need the doublequotes or the @ sign inside the brackets if i pass it as a variable? thankyou for helping :)

Comment: i have the program working perfectly if i specify the filepath hardcoded. Thats why im trying to get the openfiledialog working . im still quite new to c# :)

Comment: @AndreaVisnenzaAndy local variable, not global variable, but yes. Run your debugger, and check out the contents of `Scriptlines` just after stepping over this line to be sure, before going on with the rest of your code that uses the array. Here's some meta about posting questions to StackOverflow: [**Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); [**Accepting Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).